# Equivalent of matlab 'ans' in R

Tags: matlab, r

In matlab, you can  re-use the result of the (non affected) preceding calculous: it is stored in variable ans. Does R has something equivalent ?

Comment: You are right. I did not notice that. I guess I went with the popularity of the question which apparently misled me. No harm done though. Duplicated questions act as reference. There is no problem in having your question duped. People even answer dupes and then close them. However, If you want I can reverse this and dupe the other one instead.

Comment: Thanks Sotos, no that's fine ! not a big deal if it is still referenced.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
.Last.value
```

See also [this](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html) and [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf)

Comment: I find typing this to be time consuming and hard to remember, are there any ways to change this or create a macro that is shorter, perhaps even use _ans_?

Comment: in R Studio it's just ".la" tab and it expands to .Last.value. I do know what you mean as it's so easy to use the MATLAB terminal as a play-thing using ans[1] and ans*xyz etc etc. You could try ans <- function(){return(.Last.value)}" in R. then ans() gives you a similar thing. I'm aware this is 7 years too late...

Answer (score 9):

The value of the internal evaluation of a top-level R expression
is always assigned to `.Last.value` before further processing.