# How to assign the result of the previous expression to a variable?

Tags: r, return-value, interactive, built-in

Suppose I'm using R's interactive console, and I've just done something like this:

```
long_running_command()
```

That long-running command returns a value, and I've just realized that I wanted to assign that value to a variable instead of discard it. So how can I get that value without running the command again? Is there a command like this?

```
result = get_last_return_value()
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`.Last.value` is an answer.

[It was answered once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082716/equivalent-of-matlab-ans-in-r) but you have a better title.

Comment: Is there a more concise expression for this, or a way to configure one?

Comment: `lv <- function() .Last.value`. Then use `lv()` to get the last value.

Comment: I like the use of this lambda, but I used `ans` instead of `lv` so I could mimic my TI calculator.

Comment: One could type `.La` and hit the Tab key, that would also work.

Comment: As a side note, rstudio users can see this value in their environment panel by going to `Global options > General` and then clicking on the box labelled "Show .Last.value."

Comment: `.Last.value` is very cool. Out of interest. Is there a short hand way to call it? I know ruby has the incredibly succinct `_`, which does the same as `.Last.value` in one character! - extremely convenient.  Is there any short hand for `.Last.value` ?