# Capture last output as an R object

Tags: r, ess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign the result of the previous expression to a variable in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689279/how-to-assign-the-result-of-the-previous-expression-to-a-variable-in-r)

I'm working with R in ESS and just made the stupid mistake of running a long running function without assigning the result to a variable. So, it just printed out the result, a long string of output that looks like:

```
[[1]]
1 FALSE
[[2]]
1 TRUE
[[3]]
1 TRUE
[[4]]
1 TRUE
```

Is there any way to coerce this printed output into an R object? Either within R, or using emacs (M-x undo-my-stupid-mistake)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
out <- .Last.value
```